# Mosaicking raster tiles with different color palettes

Tags: raster, gdal, gdalwarp, mosaic

I want to create a mosaic of 35 rasters using gdal.
Using
`gdalwarp --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 8000 -wm 8000 *.tif abk.tif`
I get a fairly small output file. But I've noticed that some colours are off.
[image: Colours off after mosaicing]

It seems that some of the tiles have a slightly different color palette. So I've investigated further:
`for file in *.tif; do gdalinfo $file | grep -A25 "Color Table"; done`

And indeed, there do seem to be some differences

```
Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
    0: 0,0,0,255
    1: 126,90,57,255
    2: 126,126,126,255
    3: 0,103,158,255
    4: 0,128,47,255
    5: 0,150,253,255
    6: 224,9,21,255 <---- Oh noooo
    7: 217,111,158,255
    8: 242,130,126,255
    9: 150,150,150,255
   10: 176,176,176,255
   11: 189,230,247,255
   12: 204,230,214,255
   13: 217,227,191,255
   14: 240,224,199,255
   15: 240,242,201,255
   16: 253,245,217,255
   17: 227,227,227,255
   18: 250,222,222,255
   19: 253,250,237,255
   20: 242,242,242,255
   21: 253,253,253,255
   22: 0,0,0,255
   23: 0,0,0,255
   24: 0,0,0,255
Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
    0: 0,0,0,255
    1: 126,90,57,255
    2: 126,126,126,255
    3: 0,103,158,255
    4: 0,128,47,255
    5: 0,150,253,255
    6: 217,111,158,255
    7: 242,130,126,255
    8: 150,150,150,255
    9: 176,176,176,255
   10: 189,230,247,255
   11: 204,230,214,255
   12: 217,227,191,255
   13: 240,224,199,255
   14: 240,242,201,255
   15: 253,245,217,255
   16: 227,227,227,255
   17: 250,222,222,255
   18: 253,250,237,255
   19: 242,242,242,255
   20: 253,253,253,255
   21: 0,0,0,255
   22: 0,0,0,255
   23: 0,0,0,255
   24: 0,0,0,255
```

In ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro there is an [option](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/options-when-mosaicking-with-colormaps.htm) to specify how to handle different colour palettes. So I've tried using ArcGIS Pro but it takes forever and so far I didn't managed to generate an output file. Also, I would rather use gdal or some other FOSS.
I do know that I can use `gdal_translate -expand rgb` to convert all the images to three-band RGB but this significantly increases the file size (about twice as big).

So is there any clever way to somehow unify the colour palettes before mosaicking? I know I can trick gdalwarp by renaming files so that another tile will be used for the colour palette but this won't help because this will still yield wrong results. If I'm not mistaken, I really need to change the colour palette of each tiff?

Disclaimer: I'm well aware that [a similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27011/mosaicing-indexed-colour-rasters-with-independent-colour-tables) has been asked by [Mark Ireland](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/454/mark-ireland) nearly 9 years ago. I ask again because I suspect there is an easier way by now.

Comment: You could try applying the correct color table to all your files using gdaldem color-relief. The module name might suggest something different but I have used it to apply a color table.